# What design pattern to use for grouping report queries

Tags: c#, php, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

When quering for entities I have repositories, but in case of reports the result comes from SQL that result is just and array.I would like to know what king of class or design pattern to use for grouping those queries together. Initially I was adding these queries to the repository of the entity that was most related but I don't think is ok (repository should only return business entities of the model to my understanding)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but from what I could understand, I would go with the observer-patterns. You could use entities (from the repos) as subjects, and add the corresponding SQL reports as observers. Note however, the observer pattern usually used to notify observers of a change in the subject.